# SSRS Returning 401 Unauthorised Error when calling web service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ntlm

We have two web servers that call the SSRS service to query the reports held there. Both servers are set up identically but while one works the other returns a 401 unauthorised exception when trying to query the list.

The authentication type is NTLM and both servers have been set up on the SSRS to have browser capabilities. The applications running on both servers that call the SSRS are running as ApplicationPoolIdentity so it falls back to executing the report as Domain\ServerName$.

I can see the working server is authenticating with username Domain\ServerName$ but can't see if the non-working server is passing that through as only successful executions are logged by SSRS. Is there a way to check that somewhere? Is there a way that type of authentication could have been turned off for one server?

Thanks